# Chat room links with text after them get converted into one-boxes

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Whenever you post some link that usually converts into one-box, if there's any text after it (space character between the link and text) then it doesn't get converted. Except for chat room links.

Try posting `http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta asdfasd`

I think it's a bug that has to do with user-friendly room titles included in the link, which gets cut off with the rest of the message, without checking first if there is text after the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Embarrassingly late to this party, but: this should be fixed in a few minutes.

Comment: wow, that was fast

Comment: @berserk I think you forgot the irony/sarcasm mark: ⸮

Comment: @berserk yeah you forgot the sarcasm remark

Comment: @MarcGravell actually I realized a bit later that it was sarcastic, tho I genuinely meant about the fast fix :P (you can visit Shadow's Den for more details :P)

Comment: Awesome! Will keep in mind that sometimes all it needs is a small comment... /cc @ber :)

Comment: @berserk 2 years, 4 months and a few days? I think we've done faster than that in the past...