# Short post links with a trailing slash don't onebox in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks, onebox

Post links of the form `http://{site}/q/{PostId}/` and `http://{site}/a/{PostId}/` do not onebox in chat. I think they should. (Origin of such links: I'm in the habit of deleting UserId from short links, which leaves them ending with a slash as above.)

The slash-less counterparts do create a onebox: `http://{site}/q/{PostId}` and `http://{site}/a/{PostId}` both work.

And when "q" is expanded to "questions", the trailing slash is no longer an issue: `http://{site}/questions/{PostId}/` oneboxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately, that isn't an actual official link - and is not one that the site ever produces; we produce it with the user-id if logged in, and without either the user-id or the trailing slash if anonymous, like this (taken in incognito mode):

[image: Share link without a user id or trailing slash]

So I don't think it is automatic that it would be *assumed* to work, but: it also isn't much work to *allow* it to work; this should now be available.

Comment: While you're there, can you please take a look on [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234557/chat-room-links-with-text-after-them-get-converted-into-one-boxes)? (It appears bit "bigger" :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard done, deploying now